# Sorting Merged Cells, in a Specific Way, 'Merging' Rows without actually Merging, and Exempting Rows (et al)

Tags: excel, sorting, merge, cell, skip

I have merged cells I need to sort, and I have been asked to sort them so that a "TOTALS" bar is at the bottom of each printed page. I have supplied the totals, have logged all of the data, but I cannot find any way to sort each of the merged rows.

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Now, at the end of each page, I would need a TOTALS for how many of each gender/ethnic demographic had been hired, which is a simple matter of adding every other row into the end, etc, etc.

I can only think of a couple methods, but I don't know if Excel can do this:

1.) 'Lock In' a set of rows so that, if I go to sort them, they will sort by the first letter in each Job Title's ID, without having to unmerge.

2.) Have it so the totals bar is on the footer of every page (when I go to Print it), and updates progressively with each following page.

3.) Find a way so that the TOTALS bar is skipped when I go to sort the merged cells (which I still don't know how to do), but that won't sweep up the TOTALS bar in the Alphabetizing.

4.) Make it so I can copy + "insert" entries above other entries (and shift the remaining cells down), but so that the TOTALS row remains unaffected, the formulas don't bug out, and are exempt from the SORT and INSERT actions.

Comment: Do your cells need to be merged? By need, I mean outside of "It looks better"?

Comment: They do. I have tried rearranging the cells a variety of ways, seeing if there was a way to restructure the Report so that everything could fit tidily on one page, but still have all the same values as before, and none of my methods worked. Any other way ended up with the report stretching out onto other pages.

Mind you, these aren't my criteria I am meeting, and the Totals absolutely MUST show at the end of each printed page.

Comment: You don't really show enough info to understand what you are tryingto accomplish, but what if `Pianist Designation #: 04782` was listed in rows 271, 272 and 273, instead of requiring a merged cell? You also don't show the totals and what you would like those to look like...